# JMeter Report - No column <"VarName"> found in sample metadata

Tags: jmeter

I have configured my JMeter Simple Data Writer to output my results. However, when using the JMeter HMTL Reported generator I am receiving this error:

Generating report
An error occurred: Error while processing samples: Consumer failed with message :Consumer failed with message :Consumer failed with message :Consumer failed with message :No column <"VarName"> found in sample metadata <timeStamp,elapsed,label,responseCode,responseMessage,success,failureMessage,bytes,Latency>, check #jmeter.save.saveservice.* properties to add the missing column

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have definition for [generating a custom chart over time](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#customs_graphs) for `VarName` [sample variable](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) and it is not present in the [.jtl results](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) file.

So the options are in:

1. Remove custom chart configuration, i.e. look for the properties which start with `jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_` and either comment them out or delete these lines completely.

   Once done you should be able to generate the dashboard from that .jtl results file.
2. Add the next line to *user.properties* file:

   ```
   sample_variables=VarName
   ```

   in this case you will need to re-run your test and re-generate the dashboard using the new .jtl results file

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: Thank you so much Dmitri ...commented it out and it works a treat.